# Date formatting SQL in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have this query which I wrote for Microsoft Access and I wanted to change it to SQL Server. I am not sure how to format dates in SQL Server.

```
SELECT 
   IIF(EmentStatus > 1, IIF(IsNull([DirStartDate]), '01/01/1990', Format([DirStartDate], 'dd/mm/yyyy')),'') AS [Directorship Start Date]
FROM EeDetails
```

Comment: What does this query actually do?  Does it merely substitute January 1, 1990 for an empty date?  Ick.  If 1/1/1990 is arbitrary (and merely represents the earliest possible date), just return a zero.

Comment: yeah if the employee status is greater than 1 and director start date is 0 then 01/01/1990 will be the date

Comment: Does the date 1/1/1990 have any significance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use the `case` statement instead of `iif()` (`case` is the ANSI standard syntax supported by basically all databases).  The date formatting functions are different as well:

```
SELECT (case when EmentStatus > 1 and DirStartDate is null
             then '01/01/1990'
             when EmentStatus > 1 
             then convert(varchar(10), DirStartDate, 103)
             else ''
        end) as [Directorship Start Date]
FROM EeDetails;
```